# ActiveAdmin nested form duplicate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, activeadmin

I know there are multiple questions with a similar title to this, but I haven't found anything that resembled my problem. If there is already a solution and thus my question is a duplicate, I'm sorry - I just didn't find it, it's not that I didn't search.

I'm using ActiveAdmin with the ActiveSkin theme. I have a form for my model `Agent` where I want to use the nested forms for a `has_many` relation. I created this code in a partial:

```
<%= semantic_form_for [@agent], builder: ActiveAdmin::FormBuilder do |f| %>
    <%= f.semantic_errors %>
    <%= f.inputs 'General Information' do %>
        <%= f.input :name %>
        <%= f.input :description %>
    <% end %>
    <%= f.inputs 'Capture Columns' do %>
        <%= f.has_many :capture_columns, new_record: 'Add Column' do |column| %>
            <%= column.input :column_name %>
            <%= column.input :column_datatype %>
        <% end %>
    <% end %>
    <%= f.actions do %>
        <%= f.action :submit %>
        <li class="cancel"><%= link_to 'Cancel', :back %></li>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Basically, this is working, but it looks like this:

[image: Forms with duplicated html]

Why is the html duplicated (I checked it, it's exactly the same)? What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:
The inner HTML for the nested form is duplicated, too:
[image: Nested Form with duplicated html]

Comment: Version of Rails?  Version of ActiveAdmin? (try pre5).  My first response would be to rewrite the partial in Arbre (.arb not .erb), eg. https://activeadmin.info/5-forms.html

Comment: Rails 5.0.2 and AA from the current master branch. why do you think that abre works better?

Comment: As Fivell mentions in the GH issue the tests cover using .arb much better than .erb, which is more of an afterthought.

Comment: f.inputs in Arbre overrides and is slightly different from f.inputs using just Formtastic. <%- as suggested is worth trying also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not saying it's the right behavior, but according to [the docs](https://activeadmin.info/5-forms.html#partials), you need to avoid printing to the template when using `has_many`.

Try using `<%-` or `<%` instead of `<%=` in the `f.has_many` declaration and block.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's going to work, I run into this myself yesterday! xD

Comment: I also had to use `<%` for the `has_many` block itself, but yeah, it works! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes, that's the only place that needs changing, actually! I'll clarify the answer.

Comment: no, I must not use `<%=` inside of `has_many` either, else the content is printed twice

Comment: mmmmm. I thought I tried this, but since this is what the docs say, and you have tried it for sure... I accepted your edit! Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

There is a loop hear. The problem is simple to solve, just get in the loop and understand why it is looping and how to fix it. You should use `binding.pry` to test it. You can set a breakpoint in the form with `<% binding.pry %>` or you can print variables like `<% puts column %>` in your server log.

```
  <%= f.has_many :capture_columns, new_record: 'Add Column' do |column| %>
        <%= column.input :column_name %>
        <%= column.input :column_datatype %>
    <% end %>
```

Comment: I'll give it a try

Comment: I struggled using pry, but I tried to debug it with the normal console and wasn't able to extract any useful information...

Comment: @FlorianKoch it would be helpful if you would print in you server log 2 variables <% puts f.capture_columns %>  before the f.has_many :capture_columns and inside that <% puts column %> <% puts column.input %> Vielen Dank :)

Comment: the first (slightly modified to `f.object.capture_columns`) doesn't output anything, `column` is printed as `#<ActiveAdmin::FormBuilder:0xd021068>` and `column.input` isn't something I can put